# Fatal Error when trying to connect sftp

Tags: networking, sftp

Issues I am having with getting a sftp working correctly. I have set this up many times, but for some reason this one is not working

I have my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file set like this:

```
#hch-somename 
Match User hch-somename
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/test/data
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

If the past when setting this like this and using filezilla to connect to the sftp://ip-addr with the username and password it would drop me in the directory based off the ChrootDirectory setting in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, however what happens instead is I get an error message like this

```
Command:    Pass: *********************
Error:          FATAL ERROR: Connection reset by peer
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

Now the interesting thing is if I change the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and change the ChrootDirectory to /var/sftp I am able to get logged in with no issues at all. I have never seen this before, hopefully someone can assist me with this.

Comment: Depending on how you've set things up, you should see a more specific error in `/var/log/auth.log`. Could you update your question to include the most recent lines from that file so that someone might offer a suggestion?

Comment: Sure let me look at the log and what lines are you wanting to see?

Comment: @Matigo I did a tail -f on the auth.log and try to connect here are the results Mar  9 16:06:26 kroger-intergration-sftp sshd[26570]: Failed password for root from 167.71.139.119 port 47840 ssh2
Mar  9 16:06:26 kroger-intergration-sftp sshd[26570]: Received disconnect from 167.71.139.119 port 47840:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar  9 16:06:26 kroger-intergration-sftp sshd[26570]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 167.71.139.119 port 47840 [preauth]

why would this work with just /var/sftp in the ChrootDirecotry? Looking at this not sure if this error even makes since

Comment: Check for appropriate ownership/permissions on the chroot directory and all its components - see for example [How solve error with sftp: Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449518/how-solve-error-with-sftp-couldnt-read-packet-connection-reset-by-peer)

Comment: Don’t connect as root. So many applications will reject root connection attempts right off the bat. Create a different account and connect with that, even if it has full access to the system 

Comment: I can show you both my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, but what would you be interested in seeing from it?

Comment: @matigo the strange thing is I am not connecting as root. I am connecting as the user I create named hch-kroger-pantry that is why I am confused about where the root is coming in.

Comment: @matigo the folder is root see output  /var/sftp$ ls -l 
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 root       root    4096 Mar  9 14:12 hch-kroger-pantry  but the user I am connecting with via sftp is not root here is what I am connecting as when I use FileZilla Status:       Using username "hch-kroger-pantry". 
Command: Pass: *********************
Error:         FATAL ERROR: Connection reset by peer
Error:         Could not connect to server.

Comment: When I change the ChrootDirectory to -> /var/sftp and then connect I am seeing this Status:       Connecting to 157.245.217.108...
Status:       Using username "hch-kroger-pantry". 
Status:       Connected to 157.245.217.108
Status:       Retrieving directory listing...
Status:       Listing directory /
Status:       Directory listing of "/" successful

Comment: There must be something strange about the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. I decided to use a different server since this was pressing and it worked perfectly fine. Thank you all for your ideas and suggestions. I wish I knew what was going on with the sftp server though.